# How to split a dataframe for parallel processing and then recombine the results?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I'm looking to split up a dataframe for parallel processing in order to speed up the processing time.

What I have so far (broken code):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(iterators)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

data_split <- split(iris, iris$Species)
data_iter <- iter(data_split)

cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(
  data=data_iter,
  i = data_iter,
  .combine=dplyr::bind_rows
  
) %dopar% {
  test <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, i)
  test.lm <- broom::augment(test)
  
  return(dplyr::bind_rows(test.lm))
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Maybe an lapply within the foreach?

```
out <- foreach(it = data_iter,
               .combine = dplyr::bind_rows,
               .multicombine = TRUE,
               .noexport = ls()
) %dopar% {
  print(str(it, max.level = 1))
  out <- lapply(it, function(x) {
    test <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, subset(iris, iris$Species == iris$Species[[x]]))
    test.lm <- broom::augment(test)
  })
}
print(bind_rows(out))
return(bind_rows(out))
```

What I'm looking to do:

```
test1 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, subset(iris, iris$Species == iris$Species[[1]]))
test.lm1 <- broom::augment(test1)

test2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, subset(iris, iris$Species == iris$Species[[2]]))
test.lm2 <- broom::augment(test2)

test3 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, subset(iris, iris$Species == iris$Species[[3]]))
test.lm3 <- broom::augment(test3)

testdat <- bind_rows(test.lm1,test.lm2,test.lm3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer with the `furrr` package:

```
library(furrr)

plan(cluster, workers = 3)

data_split <- split(iris, iris$Species)

testdat <- furrr::future_map_dfr(data_split, function(.data){
  test <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, .data)
  broom::augment(test)
})

plan(cluster, workers = 1)

testdat
```

Comment: No need for the **doParallel** package and its `registerDoParallel()` registration.  If it's the `makeCluster()` and `stopCluster()` you're after, then they're in the **parallel** package.

Comment: You can also skip `makeCluster()` and use `plan(cluster, workers = 3)` directly.

Comment: Does `furrr` have a stop cluster function?

Comment: If you use `plan(cluster, workers = 3)` then you can stop that cluster by changing to another plan, e.g. `plan(sequential)`.  This is from the **future** package that **furrr** builds on top.

Comment: BTW, use `plan(multisession, workers = 3)`, which basically the same as `plan(cluster, workers = 3)`.  I only used `cluster` in my first comment to make it as similar as possible to what you've already got.